# Adding marker on a leaflet map

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, geojson, geodjango

I'm very new to GIS and for learning I started with building a simple web app with GeoDjango. I am using django-leaflet. Since I have a very limited knowledge I am facing many challenges. I'm trying to put a specifc marker on my map as a test

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import point
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

class Points(gismodels.Model):
      data_lat = 44.915223
     data_long = -93.209741


     @property

     def geom(self):
         return point(self.data_lat, self.data_long, srid=4326)
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

about.html

```
<body>
      <h1> Map  </h1>
     {% leaflet_map "main" callback="main_map_init" %}

      <script type="text/javascript">

          function main_map_init (map, options){

                var dataurl = '{% url "data" %}';

               $.getJSON('dataurl', function(data) {

                   L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
               })
          }
      </script>

</body>
```

I'm having issue with data not being passed on to map. It would be nice if someone could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In about.html, the correct code would be (supposing data would be a link to the geojson created on the fly

```
var dataurl = '{% url "data" %}';
$.getJSON(dataurl, function(data) {
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
})
```

I suggest you to see for reference http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html and try to create a map manually in an html page to see how it works, then you can add content dynamically with Python.

Comment: I have that line in my code. And it still does not work.

Comment: The first argument to getJSON function should be a valid url to the JSON file. See the developer console of your browser if there's an error message. The difference between my code and your is this: you are trying to get data.json from the same directory, but seems that you want the data to come from dataurl variable.

Comment: I have an app that uses code identical in syntax to this answer and it works. It is also in several online samples.